# Highcharts strange lines

Tags: highcharts

I am try to draw simple chart using this code:

```
:coffee
  requestData = () ->
    $.ajax
    url:  "#{ build_chart_data_track_url(@track.id) }"
    type: "GET"
    dataType: "json"
    success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
      chart.addSeries({
        type: 'spline',
        name: "Price",
        data: data.price,
        connectEnds: false,
        color: 'orange',
      });


    chart = Highcharts.chart 'chart',
      chart:
        zoomType: 'x'
      events:
        load: requestData

      title:
        text: "some text"
```

But I see strange lines when data is absent (or something else?). How I can disable it and leave only one line with my data?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The issue was in Ajax loaded data format.